# Bootstrap navbar: collapsed menu not expanding on small resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using bootstrap for my navbar in a blog site I'm creating. When I reduce the screen size to mobile, the menu items collapse as desired, however when I click on the expand icon it doesn't react. Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  NUFC Blog</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>   Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>. </li>
  </ul>
  <% if(currentUser && currentUser.id === "**************")  { %>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/blogs/new"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>   New Blog <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <% } %>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <% if(!currentUser){ %>
    <li><a href="/login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Sign up</a></li>
    <% } else { %>
    <li><a href="/profile"><div id="header-user-icon" <%if(currentUser.image ==""){ %>
          style="background:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unique-round-blue/93/user-512.png); background-size: cover">
          <% } else { %>
          style="background:url(<%=currentUser.image%>); background-size: cover">
          <% } %>
          </div> <%= currentUser.username %> </a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Sign out </a></li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Obviously I've edited this a fair amount from the initial bootstrap code so I figured it was probably something I had added that was causing the issue. However, I ran a test by commenting out this code and copying the exact bootstrap example into the same document and it still would not work, which leads me to believe I'm missing a plugin of some kind? Really can't work out what I'm missing to get this working.

Update: full code:

This is what is in my header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>NUFC Blog</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"</link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"</link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/components/accordion.css"</link>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hif/2/25/Newcastle_United_Logo.png">
</head>

<body>


<!-- nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  NUFC Blog</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>   Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <% if(currentUser && currentUser.id === "*******") { %>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/blogs/new"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>   New Blog <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <% } %>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <% if(!currentUser){ %>
    <li><a href="/login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Sign up</a></li>
    <% } else { %>
    <li><a href="/profile"><div id="header-user-icon" <%if(currentUser.image ==""){ %>
          style="background:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unique-round-blue/93/user-512.png); background-size: cover">
          <% } else { %>
          style="background:url(<%=currentUser.image%>); background-size: cover">
          <% } %>
          </div> <%= currentUser.username %> </a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Sign out </a></li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<% if(error && error.length > 0) { %>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <%= error %>
        </div>
<% } %>
        </div>

<% if(success && success.length > 0) { %>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <%= success %>
        </div>
<% } %>
    </div>
```

And then I reference jQuery in a separate footer:

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"
integrity="sha256-wPFJNIFlVY49B+CuAIrDr932XSb6Jk3J1M22M3E2ylQ="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src = "/ajax.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And then obviously link the header and footer to every other document within the project with

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
```

and

```
<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Comment: Did you add js file of bootstrap and jquery correctly?

Comment: I believe so! I'm using the bootstrap CDN in the head section: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"</link>

Comment: And jquery as follows: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-wPFJNIFlVY49B+CuAIrDr932XSb6Jk3J1M22M3E2ylQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wqxyjmt5/   Is this what you have now?

Comment: yes - I'm actually referencing the jQuery in a separate document at the moment as the code I have pasted above is in my 'header' file and the jQuery CDN is in the 'footer'. Having said that, I did experiment by including them in the same file as well and had the same result.

Comment: could you posted your complete code with snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out in the end and was very simple. I was referencing the Bootstrap CSS CDN but not the javascript one. I put this in and works perfectly now.